# Removing articles in domain names

Tags: articles

There are not a lot of domain names which have articles in their names.

> For example, as I know, the initial name for facebook was thefacebook. And as I understand for native speakers now there is no problem that "the" was removed.

So if I'm going to name a site, for example , **GiveMeSpoon.com or GiveMeBook.com** or something like that, will that be ok for native speakers' ears? Although the right grammatical variants for those names should include using articles and would be: **GiveMeASpoon.com and GiveMeABook.com**. My question is about
Thank you! :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because naming, and naming protocols / fashions, are off-topic.

Comment: ...and now we have a problem. The "dupe" has no answer, but this post has already accepted one...what to do? Sounds meta...

Comment: @Cascabe, please,delete that dupe question. I like this answer. I think it's very important and intersting theme "not using articles where they are usually used". In news and domain names. I dont understand why the people downvoted me and the answer.

Comment: Your other question has no answers, so you can delete it yourself. Go to the bottom of the question and you will see the delete button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a native English speaker, and Facebook.com was a great example of how some companies opt to drop articles from their domain names. However, it worked for Facebook because the article was at the beginning of the company/domain name. Articles are often used to provide context for a noun by defining which noun is being talked about. For example, "She threw the ball" vs "She threw a ball". This sentence would not work if it was read as, "She threw ball". On the other hand, removing "the" from "theFacebook" works because in that case "Facebook" is the noun, and there are no verbs acting on the noun, so the specific "Facebook" is not necessary. That is why "Book.com" and "Spoon.com" work.

Comment: Essentially, dropping the article at the beginning of a domain is unnecessary because the noun that it is specifying does not have any verb acting on it.

Comment: In the other examples, "throw" was acting on the "ball", but which ball wasn't specified, hence the need for an article.